# Could not invoke RNCookieManagerAndroid.getAll

Tags: android, cookies, react-native

Right now I'm trying to use this a package called [react-native-cookies](https://github.com/joeferraro/react-native-cookies) and I'm having trouble using any of the functions listed (for android). I'm encountering this error, which points to line 279 of BaseJavaModule.java, in ReactAndroid/src/main/java/com/facebook/react/bridge/BaseJavaModule.java

```
    } catch (InvocationTargetException ite) {
      // Exceptions thrown from native module calls end up wrapped in InvocationTargetException
      // which just make traces harder to read and bump out useful information
      if (ite.getCause() instanceof RuntimeException) {
        throw (RuntimeException) ite.getCause();
      }
      throw new RuntimeException(
          "Could not invoke " + BaseJavaModule.this.getName() + "." + mMethod.getName(), ite);
    }
```

The line `throw new RuntimeException(` is where the error message points to. The function I'm trying to run in js is `CookieManager.getAll((err,cookie) => { });` (so i'm not even trying to do anything, just trying to run the getAll function).

Does anyone know why this error is occurring? Also, can someone help me figure out how to debug the native code running in the background? The chrome debugging only seems to really help when debugging reactjs itself, not the android code running in the background.

If anyone knows of a better way to obtain cookies for storing in react native android, that'd be appreciated too.

```
packages.json:
  "dependencies": {
    "fs": "0.0.2",
    "nconf": "^0.8.4",
    "react": "^0.14.5",
    "react-native": "^0.23.1",
    "react-native-cookies": "^1.0.0",
    "react-native-drawer": "^1.16.7",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^1.3.4",
    "react-timer-mixin": "^0.13.3"
  }
```